# API For REST Request From NodeJS to Backend

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest

I have an application in which angular sends the data to nodejs and nodejs send it to the backend which is running in Jetty.Can anyone suggest what would be the best API/approach to send REST request from NodeJs to Backend?

Comment: Is the jetty backend also exposed via REST?

Comment: @RobertMoskal Yes its exposed via REST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't want to sister your jetty api in node (endpoint for endpoint). You probably want to handle all requests that match a certain path, say /api and then pass those on to jetty. That is, if you can. Maybe the jetty api is not to be directly exposed.

Either way you should use the most excellent request library to call jetty from your node endpoints:

https://github.com/request/request